# Tuples: No matching function for call to 'get'

Tags: c++, tuples

I have 3 structs : `Student`, `Citizen`, `Employee`. I want user to be able to choose what struct they want to work with (`std::vector` of structs, actually). Since there's no way to define type at runtime, I created all 3 vectors, but will use only one of them (depending on the user's choice), others will stay empty:

```
std::vector<Student> container_student;
std::vector<Citizen> container_citizen;
std::vector<Employee> container_employee;
auto containers = make_tuple(container_student, container_citizen, container_employee);
std::cout << "Enter:\n0 to operate \"Student\" struct\n1 to operate \"Citizen\" struct\n2 to operate \"Employee\" struct\n";
std::cin >> container_type;
auto container = std::get<container_type>(containers);
```

But I get `No matching function for call to 'get'`, even though `container_type` is an `int` and `containers` is a `tuple`.

Edit: understandable, `auto` can't make magic and I still try to make `container`'s type to depend on runtime. But even if I try to use `std::get<container_type>(containers)` (probably `define` would help) instead of `container` in functions etc., I get the same error, which is not understandable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, what you're proposing isn't possible in C++. The C++ typing and template system works at compile-time, where information read in from the user isn't available. As a result, anything passed into a template's angle braces needs to be determinable at compile-time. In your case, the number the user enters, indicating which option they want to select, is only knowable at runtime.

There are some routes you could take to achieve the same result, though. For example, one option would be to do something like this:

```
if (container_type == 0) {
    auto container = std::get<0>(containers);
    /* ... */
} else if (container_type == 1) {
    auto container = std::get<1>(containers);
    /* ... */
} /* etc */
```

Here, all the template angle braces are worked out at compile-time. (Then again, if this is what you're going to be doing, you wouldn't need the tuple at all. ^_^)

Another option would be to use templates, like this:

```
template <typename T> void doSomething(std::vector<T>& container) {
    /* Put your code here */
}

/* Then, back in main... */

if (container_type == 0) {
    doSomething(container_student);
} else if (container_type == 1) {
    doSomething(container_citizen);
} /* etc */
```

This still requires you to insert some code to map from integer types to the functions you want to call, but it leaves you the freedom to have a `container` variable (the one in `doSomething`) that you can treat generically at that point.

It's basically the Fundamental Theorem of Software Engineering in action - all problems can be solved by adding another layer of indirection. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: But how do I extend life of `container` beyond `if-else` constructions? I tried it actually, with `new` etc., but it didn't work.

Comment: There isn't, unfortunately, a way to declare `container` to have type "whatever the user provides at runtime," and with `std::vector` there's no direct way to do this. Given that you're trying to store items of three different types, I suspect (?) that you'd be using different code in each case to manipulate the items. Can you elaborate a bit more about what you want to do and why you'd like to have one `container` variable? Depending on what you're aiming for there may be ways to approximate this.

Comment: I have some overloaded functions for every container type, and also some unique. It seems to be that to make it as a menu with 3 choices is the only way.

Comment: @AlexeiSavitsky Ah, gotcha. Edited my answer with some code that has a small bit of code that selects which argument to pass into a helper template function that then has the `container` variable. Hope this helps!